# Changing employers on TIer 2 visa- How long do I have if new CoS doesn't come through before my current Tier 2 visa expires?

Tags: working-visas, immigration

I'm an Australian currently on a Tier 2 general Visa. I'm changing employers on Tier 2 visa- I gave notice 7 weeks ago (I'm a teacher hence the long notice period) and my contract will end with the current employer on 31st August. My new job is waiting for the new CoS to come through but have just been told it could be up to 18 weeks!? I am meant to be starting my new job in September however if this doesn't come through in time I may not be able to start the job.

My questions:
1) How long do I have after my visa expires on 31st August before I have to leave the UK?

2) Will I have to leave before this? 
Or is there a '28 day grace period' (I read about this on this website)

3) Can I apply for my new Tier 2 from anywhere outside the UK or will I have to go back to Australia to do so?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: 18 weeks seems very long. Is your employer a premium sponsor for applicants? If so, it shouldn't take very long at all. Also, I believe they just need evidence you have reapplied for a new visa for you to continue working in the UK at the time of your visa expiration.

Comment: Hope you are well and the process went through.
I am in similar situation. Can you please let me know, if I can apply for a replacement visa once I have resigned the Job? My job is in shortage occupation list. I am already serving my notice period with couple of weeks left. Any help on this would be great. Regards,
Praveen.